# Postfix error. 450 4.7.1 Client host rejected: cannot find your reverse hostname

Tags: postfix, smtp

I have a problem with postfix and its configuration. I can send emails to external sites (gmail, outlook, yahoo...) but I can't send emails locally.

For example, if my domain is myfantasticdomain.com, I can't send an email from user1@myfantasticdomain.com to user2@myfantasticdomain.com

This is the configuration I have:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = localhost, localhost.localdomain
myhostname = myfantasticdomain.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter =
relayhost =
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
```

I have no idea what is the problem.

Thanks

Comment: `mydestination` doesn't includes `myfantasticdomain.com`

Comment: I just included it and still not working

Answer (score 1):

You have manually excluded `myhostname` from your `mydestination`, which by default has it. (This also happens if you pick some *local delivery only* setting on a configuration wizard.)

> [`mydestination`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mydestination) (default: `$myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost`)
>
> The list of domains that are delivered via the [`$local_transport`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#local_transport) mail
>   delivery transport. By default this is the Postfix [local(8)](http://www.postfix.org/local.8.html) delivery
>   agent which looks up all recipients in `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/aliases`.
>   The SMTP server validates recipient addresses with
>   `$local_recipient_maps` and rejects non-existent recipients. See also
>   the local domain class in the [`ADDRESS_CLASS_README`](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_CLASS_README.html) file.
>
> The default `mydestination` value specifies names for the local machine
>   only. On a mail domain gateway, you should also include [$mydomain](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mydomain).

So your options:

- Add the domain via `$myhostname` variable:

  ```
  mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain $mydomain
  ```
- Add the domain directly:

  ```
  mydestination = example.com, localhost.$mydomain $mydomain
  ```
- For separate aliases for this domain, use [Postfix Virtual Domain Hosting](http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html), instead.

Comment: I've add "mydomain" variable and changed "mydestination" variable, and stil not working.

Answer (score -1):

Did you get your correct hostname by using dig ptr ?
For example for the ip 192.168.0.1:

dig ptr 1.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa +short

Please make sure your Server is using valid nameserver (/etc/resolv.conf) or know your hostname in /etc/hosts.

Comment: This is not DNS related problem.

Comment: dig command return nothing (I don't know if this is correct...). The nameserver I have on resolv.conf is the IP,